# Bypass domain transfer time

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-registrar

Is there any way out to bypass the domain transfer wait time ie up to 5 days

I have a domain that was due for renewal and on the last day I made a request to transfer that domain. Its been around 60 hours and site is still down. I tried to renew the domain from the current registrar but it produced some error notice like action required from registrar. The registrar of the domain is www.publicdomainregistry.com

Tried to contact registrar but no answer/favorable results.

Comment: Which TLD?  In some cases, particularly clueful CCTLDs, direct contact with the national registry can be helpful.

Comment: its .com domain

Comment: Sorry, then all bets are off.  Why on earth would you try to transfer it on the last day of validity?

Comment: That's what I think, I was out of my mind. I would advise everyone to go thorough this question before transferring their domains :(

There are some registrar which provide an option to bypass this time. I thought, maybe I will get lucky :)

Comment: Well, you sound like a sadder but wiser man (good for you on that latter point).  I hope someone comes up with a good answer to the question, or failing that, your domain pops back into life at some point, and the problem goes away.  Live and learn!

Comment: Thanks buddy. I hope everyone to read this question and help me if there is some why out.